# A riddle of honour

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Man, you went past me again!
>   Seriously, didn't you see me sitting here?
>   Drinking water quietly then,
>   Reminds me of the land of some deer...
>
> I got confused in these mountains
>   I'll go backwards just for you, my friend.
>   And I don't know if this riddle has an end,
>   But can you guess who I am?

Comment: Are the last 3 lines relevant?

Comment: @Techidiot I bet the 6th and 7th lines are, at least.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you may be

> Lap

Man, you went past me again!

> To lap is to overtake by one complete circuit

Seriously, didn't you see me sitting here?

> the waist to the knees when in a sitting position

Drinking water quietly then

> animals may lap water

Reminds me of the land of some deer...

> lapland :)

I got confused in these mountains

> in the ALPs

I'll go backwards just for you, my friend.

> pal - reversed

And I don't know if this riddle has an end

> The riddle might not end as it's just a lap and number of laps are not mentioned - suggestion inspired by @Techidiot (thanks!) - any mistake is my lapse.

The title

> a lap of honour - an extra lap at the end of a race a winner may perform - just for congratulations

Comment: What's the last spoiler supposed to mean? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: Nice answer! +1 Should be the one.

Comment: @dcfyj - thanks for this question - I clarified the answer with some explanation.

Comment: Ah, Never heard the term before

Comment: Also, the riddle might not end as its just a lap and number of laps are not mentioned :)

Comment: Certainly seems to fit very well!